# Sony (Remote API) DSC-QX30 firmware update

Tags: camera, sony

The DSC-QX30 I have does not support the "getContentCount", and get ContentList", so there is no way to transfer the images from the card. However, according to the Remote API 2.1, it supports all those. I wonder I can get a firmware update to solve the problem. Does anyone know where I can get the latest firmware? The eSupport page does not offer any firmware but the pC application software.

Comment: Or, is there another way to transfer and delete images in that camera?

Comment: How are you coming to the conclusion that "getContentCount" and "getContentList" are not supported?

Comment: Run "getEvent" with version 1.2, those functions are not in the supported list. Run it with version 1.3 specified, returned error 14: Unsupported Version.

Comment: Marlin, one more thing: could you guys in Sony add a function that reads out the camera's serial id, or MAC id ? In law enforcement field, we have to know exactly which camera took the picture.

Comment: What is the result when you call "getVersions"?  Does it return 1.3 as supported?  Have you tried calling "getMethodTypes" on the /avContent service?  If so, does it return those methods as unsupported?

Comment: Regarding the feature request, I will let our team know about it.

Comment: Marlin, I run the "getVersions", it returns result":[["1.0","1.1","1.2"]]. Seems like the QX30 does not support version 1.3. Calling "getMethodTypes" also shows it does not have anything in version 1.3

Comment: "getContentCount" is supported in v1.2 so you should be able to access it.  Can you tell me what version of the FW you are currently running?